# What is the Java equivalent of __builtin_clz?

Tags: java, c

I need a Java equivalent of `__builtin_clz`.

It feels like the answer should be `Long.numberOfLeadingZeros` but they return completely different answers.

I'm starting to wonder if there is a low-level reason for this - maybe endianness? or some quirk of unsigned?

EDIT: False alarm. This is purely caused by a typo - the original code actually calls `__builtin_ctzll` and is matched by `Long.numberOfTrailingZeros`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False alarm: Caused by a typo - I actually needed `__builtin_ctzll` instead, which now makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 4):

`Long.numberOfLeadingZeros` is precisely correct.

The fact that you get different answers is because C. C does not define what `int` means. Therefore, the answer that `__builtin_clz(a)` gives is different on every box you run it on: It depends on the bit width of `int`, and as per the C standard, the bit width of an `int` is whatever is convenient for the system you're compiling for. If it's 32-bit (that's a very common bit width), `__builtin_clz(16)` would return 27. If it's 64-bit (also quite common), `__builtin_clz(16)` would return 59.

Java doesn't generally 'do' the whole *undefined* thing. In java, unlike C, `int` is a signed 32-bit number. No matter what VM, version, platform, or OS you're running it on or compiled it on. Similarly, a long is signed 64-bit.

Nevertheless, `Long.numberOfLeadingZeroes` effectively treats the number as unsigned just like `__builtin_clz` does: That means `__builtin_clz(x)`, where x is a negative number, always returns 0 (or should, according to the C spec), and `Long.numberOfLeadingZeros` does the exact same thing: Always returns 0 (no leading zero bits), for negative numbers.

In other words, on 64-bit systems, `__builtin_clz(x)` is matched perfectly by `Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(x)` in java. On 32-bit systems, `__builtin_clz(x)` returns 32 less than that (`__builtin_clz(16)` on 64-bit is 59, but on 32-bit, it's 27), and in java, you'd have to use `Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros()` instead. `Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(16)` returns 27. Just like `__builtin_clz(16)` would , if targeting a system where `int` is defined as 32-bit (it would be, if targeting 32-bit processors).

Comment: *In other words, on 64-bit systems, `__builtin_clz(x)` is matched perfectly by `Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(x)` in java*... not exactly: `__builtin_clz` would match `Long.numberOfLeadingZeros` on systems where `int` has 64 bits, which is quite unusual, as `int` still has 32 bits on most 64-bit systems. Conversely, `__builtin_clzll` is usually a match for `Long.numberOfLeadingZeros`.

Answer (score -1):

`__builtin_clz()` counts the number of leading zeroes in a non-zero `int` value. This number depends on the representation of type `int`, thus has not direct equivalent in java because the number of bits in C standard integer types such as `int`, `long` and `long long` is implementation defined, whereas the java specification fixes the size and representation of types `int` and `long`.

In addition to `__builtin_clz(int)`, gcc defines `__builtin_clzl(long)` and `__builtin_clzll(long long)`. On most current systems, the C ABI defines `int` with 32 bits and `long long` with 64 bits, making `Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(int)` and `Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(long)` equivalent respectively to `__builtin_clz` and `__builtin_clzll`. Note however that the java functions have defined behavior for a zero argument which the C builtins do not have, as a consequence of their implementation as a single CPU instruction (on some architectures).

`__builtin_ctz(int)`, `__builtin_ctzl(long)` and `__builtin_ctzll(long long)` count the number of trailing zeroes in a non-zero argument of the corresponding type. For a non zero value, the number of trailing zeroes only depends on the value of the argument, not its type size. The corresponding java methods are `Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(int)` and `Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(long)`. These methods are defined for all argument values and return `32` and `64` respectively for a zero argument.